# Kinvey: Does it provide access to Rest APIs in various ways

Tags: android, api, backend, kinvey, mbaas

Kinvey allows to insert, delete or retrieve data via Model classes. But when we use normal rest APIs then we are free to send data in body or header of Rest APIs. Also we have various options like GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc.

Does Kinvey provide support to above? I dont know whether I should go with Kinvey or should I use any other MBaas platform instead

Any help would be appreciated.. !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kinvey offers a client REST API. You can evaluate the interface by reviewing the documentation at the following URL to decide if it meets your needs.

http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/

Regards,

Billy

Comment: Thanks Will check it